# Call LWC Component in the URL

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

Is there a way that we can call LWC component in the URL?

Today in Aura component, we can call it using : `/lightning/cmp/c__TestCmp?oppid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

Similarly, Can we do the same for LWC also?

When I tried calling the LWC component using : `/lightning/cmp/c__TestLWC?oppid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX` it is giving the error Page not found.

Any help?

Comment: URL Addressable is not supported in LWC yet, as far as I know.